# Bound sesquilinear form $C*$-algebras

Tags: normed-spaces, c-star-algebras, sesquilinear-forms

I am currently taking lectures on $C^*$-algebras. I have a question related to this topic, precisely on linear functional on these spaces.

Suppose $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra, with a faithful normal state $\phi$.

On $A^n$, we define an inner product by taking for $x,y\in A^n$, $\langle x,y\rangle_{\phi}=\sum_{k=1}^n\phi(y_i^*x_i)$,

My question is the following. If $T$ is a complex matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

The action of $T$ on $A^n$ is define as usual by matrix multiplication over vectors.

Does the following inequality holds :
$\lvert \langle Tx,y\rangle_{\phi}\rvert\leq\lVert T\rVert_{op}\lVert x\rVert\lVert y\rVert$.

With $op$ is the usual operator norm for matrices.

Thanks for you help.

#Edit#
The question as been answered.

Comment: As an alternative to Martin's answer, you may as well notice that the action of $M_n(\mathbb C)$ on $A^n$ gives rise to a $\ast$-representation of $M_n(\mathbb C)$ on the completion of $A^n$ with respect to $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_\phi$. Then this inequality follows from the fact that $\ast$-representations are contractive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You have, using first Cauchy-Schwarz for $\phi$ and then for the usual inner product in $\mathbb C^n$,
\begin{align}
|\langle Tx,y\rangle|
&\leq\sum_k|\phi(y_k^*(Tx)_k)|
\leq \sum_k\phi(y_k^*y_k)^{1/2}\phi((Tx)_k^*(Tx)_k)^{1/2}\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\Big[\sum_k\phi(y_k^*y_k)\Big]^{1/2}\Big[\sum_k\phi((Tx)_k^*(Tx)_k)\Big]^{1/2}\\[0.3cm]
&=\|y\|\,\Big[\sum_{k,j}\phi(x_j^*T_{kj}^*T_{kj}x_j)\Big]^{1/2}\\[0.3cm]
&=\|y\|\,\Big[\sum_{k,j}\phi(x_j^*(T^*)_{jk}T_{kj}x_j)\Big]^{1/2}\\[0.3cm]
&=\|y\|\,\Big[\sum_{j}\phi(x_j^*(T^*T)_{jj}x_j)\Big]^{1/2}\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\|T\|\,\|y\|\,\Big[\sum_{j}\phi(x_j^*x_j)\Big]^{1/2}\\[0.3cm]
&=\|T\|\,\|x\|\,\|y\|.
\end{align}

Comment: I'd like to make sure I got the idea of the proof. By $Tx_k$ you mean $(Tx)_k,$ right ?

Comment: That was definitely not right the way it was written. Take a look now.

Comment: Thanks. Now it's fine as a double sum showed up. I had a slightly different approach: $\langle Tx,y\rangle={\rm Tr}(TA)$, where $a_{ij}=φ(y^∗_jx_i).$ Then I estimate by the product of $\|T\|$ and $\|A\|_1.$

Comment: Nice. That's a good way of taking advantage the $T$ has scalar entries.